# Which Pagination approach is better when the number of items are too much?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a search result which contains thousands of items. I don't want to return the hole result from db, since maybe the client don't want to visit all pages and reviewing first pages. So I want to manage pagination in stored procedure of my SQL Server database and uses the page number and page size... .

I want to use a pagination in view and send the current page and .. to controller, then use the parameters to send into my business layer and db. And also use the parameters to set the next page in view.

- What's your opinion about this approach?
- If it's reasonable, How can I implement that? any tool?

Comment: [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: I have read it before and used it. But I don't want to load the hole result and manage the pagination in controller. But I want to have just a pagination in view, and manage that in db. I don't want to select * where .... . I want to use sp in sql server that manages the the skip and take and returns other remain results base on page size

Comment: It not loading the whole result - `PagedList` uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()`. But if you want do do it manually, then go ahead. If your having trouble implementing it, show what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: OK thanks. (Does it need to get down vote?! :) )

Comment: The question is off-topic for SO (take your pick - too broad, asking for opinions and asking for tools)

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, you can use SQL based pagination, write stored procedure with input parameter to get necessary records from  database. And then use fluent API to handle this stored procedure in your own paging method. You can also use this stored procedure for sorting. PagedList is another option. Simple to use. A lot of tutorial is out there.

Comment: I can get correct result from db with pagination. The problem was UI. Now I solved that using PagedListPager and Session. Please check comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028148/how-to-send-object-of-object-in-pagedlistpager