# How to send object of object in PagedListPager?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have an action method that gets an object called InputObj.

```
public class InputObj<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }

    public int PageSize { get; set; }

    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And the action method is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Search(InputObj<USER> input)
    {
```

and in view I used PagedListPager if the search had results:

```
                    @if (ViewBag.Result != null)
                    {
                        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.Result, page => Url.Action("Search", new InputObj<USER>
                   {
                       Item = Model.Item,
                       PageNumber = page,
                       PageSize = Model.PageSize
                   }))
                    }
```

But when I want to go to other pages, The `Item` is `null`, but PageNumber and PageSize are initialized correctly. In querystring I have

```
/User/Search?Item=MyApplication.Model.User&PageSize=2&PageNumber=2
```

It seems we have .toString() here for Item!

Comment: in your query string when you assign to Item, is MyApplication.Model.User serialized?

Comment: You can't pass properties which are complex types using `Url.Action()` (or any other method that generates a `RouteValueDictionary`). Internally the method uses `.ToString()` of each property value.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be can't` (not can). You simply cannot do it - its not a recursive method (and if it was, you would likely exceed the query string limit and throw an exception)

Comment: And  No alternative way?

Comment: No. And even if you passed each individual property of `USER` I'm not sure the `DefaultModelBinder` would infer the type and bind it.

Comment: Ok. I did it using session. But if any other way  I gladly welcomed!

Comment: if (input.Item != null)
            {
                Session["searchItem"] = input.Item;
            }
            else
            {
                input.Item = Session["searchItem"] as T_CLUB_CUSTOMER;
            }